# Ethers.js and Metamask RPC Error Already processing eth_requestAccount

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I'm having a problem using Metamask with Ethers.js. I have the following set-up:

Metamask installed on Edge browser.
Hardhat localhost node.
Node.js localhost http server.

I can connect to Hardhat via Metamask without any problems, but if I close the browser and open it again (or just "Lock" Metamask to logout) I can no longer connect to Metamask and instead get this error:

RPC Error: Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait. {code: -32002, message: 'Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait.'}

No matter how long I wait I get the above error. I understand what the message means, but don't see any reason why it should appear in these circumstances.

Here's my (abbreviated) code:

```
provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
```

I want Metamask to pop-up as normal and ask for a password and it doesn't. I have to open Metamask, login, disconnect "localhost" from the list of connected sites, then I can connect via the above code. But as I said, if I then logout of Metamask or close and re-open the browser, I get the RPC error.

I'd really appreciate any help on this!